# Why I can't print the "team"? Whats the problem with the Scanner?

Tags: java

I don't understand why the team variable is not printed. What's the problem?
Why that part of code doesn't work?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCases = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(testCases);
        for(int i = testCases; i > 0; i--) {
            int nTeams = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println(nTeams);
            for(int k = nTeams; k>0; k--) {
                System.out.println("Entrou no looping de Times!");
                String team = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println(team);
                String[] arrTeam = team.split(" ");
                for( int j = 0; j<arrTeam.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println(arrTeam[j]);
                }
            }
        }
                        
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: My advice : NEVER use nextInt() do `Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine())`

Comment: Humm... maybe it does.. I'll try to change the code. Thanks!

Comment: At a first try didn't work

Comment: And...? You entered what, what do you want it to print, and what did it print in reality.

Comment: It was just 3 lines... integer, integer and a simple string with 3 words...

Comment: ......? So what your code NOW?